# Solve the differential equation $\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz}=\frac{dz}{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz}=\frac{dz}{x^2-y^2}$$

Till now, I learnt how to solve first order  differential equations, with one independent variable, but it seems the number of independent variable in here in more than one. I feel, $z$ might be an independent variable. Also, it might be the case, that this equation (given) has only one independent variable that is, $x$ and more than one dependent variable i.e $z$ and $y.$

But I don't know which is the case specifically.

Ignoring this, I tried solving the problem as:

We have $$\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz}=\frac{dz}{x^2-y^2}.$$

We consider, $$\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz}.$$

This means, $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y+zx}{x+yz}.$ Now, this is homogeneous differential equation and hence we assume, $y=vx$.

Again, $y=vx\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$ and substituting these, into $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y+zx}{x+yz},$ we have,

$$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{v+z}{1+vz}\implies \frac{-(z+v)dv}{(v+1)^2}=\frac{dx}{x}\implies \int\frac{-(z+v)dv}{(v+1)^2}=\int\frac{dx}{x}\implies \frac{z-1}{v+1}-\log|v+1|=\log x+c\implies \frac{(z-1)x}{y+x}-\log\frac{y+x}{x^2}=c,$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

So, $\frac{(z-1)x}{y+x}-\log\frac{y+x}{x^2}=c,$ is a solution of the differential equation $\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz}.$

---

The thing is, I solved the differential equation $\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz},$ considering $z$ as a constant with no prior justification. I dont know, whether the thing I just did, was at all legit or not.

I want to know, whether my method of solving the differential equation $\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz},$ is justified or not. If it's justified, then how so?

If it's not, then how should we proceed to solve this problem?

Also, I am unable to solve the differential equation $-\frac{dy}{x+yz}=\frac{dz}{x^2-y^2}.$ Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Finally, I want to know if there's any standard way of approaching differential equations of more than "two variables " of this sort $\frac{dx}{y+zx}=-\frac{dy}{x+yz}=\frac{dz}{x^2-y^2}.$

Comment: humm, this looks like a first order pde for me with dependent variable being $z(x,y)$ written in what is called Lagrangian form $\frac{dx}{a}+ \frac{dy}{b} = \frac{dz}{c}$. No?

Comment: @Nasser Pardon me, but I don't have any idea 'bout PDE's. Neither do I know what Lagrangian form is? Surely, I have heard about it, though.

Comment: Where did you get this from? A book? Is the chapter on pde's or ode's?  A pde is where one variable depends on two others. in ode, a variable depends only on one other variable.

Comment: @Nasser No, not from a book, but a handout of a set of problems, focussing on ODEs . Our professor prepared it for us, some years back.

Comment: OK, but I bet this is a pde. And that is my final answer. Look up the Lagrangian form for first order pde's and you will see the similarity. Otherwise it makes no sense as ode. Do you know even what is the dependent variable and which are the independent variables?

Comment: @Nasser Nope, that's what I mentioned in the originial post.

Comment: While the motivation for the problem’s creator probably was a PDE—Google the method of chacteristics for details—this is an entirely well-posed system of ODEs regardless of that context. (One can either consider $x,y,z$ to be functions of some independent variable $t$, as in the answer below, or try to treat two of the three as functions of the third.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume this is a shorthand for the system of ODE's

$$\begin{Bmatrix}\frac{dx}{dt}=&y+zx\\\frac{dy}{dt}=&-x-zy\\\frac{dz}{dt}=&x^2-y^2\end{Bmatrix}$$

It is easy to see by direct differentiation that

$$\frac{d}{dt}(xy+z)=x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dz}{dt}=0\iff xy+z=C_1$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2-z^2)=2(y\frac{dy}{dt}+x\frac{dx}{dt}-z\frac{dz}{dt})=0\iff x^2+y^2-z^2=C_2$$

which means that we have found two integrals of motion for this system of ODE's. It is then possible to solve for $x,y$ in terms of $z$ and the arbitrary constants $C_1,C_2$ and substitute into the $z$ equation to calculate the trajectory $z(t)$. In particular, we find the expression

$$(x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-(2xy)^2=((z+1)^2+A_-)((z-1)^2+A_+)~~, ~~ A_{\pm}:=C_2\pm 2C_1-1 $$

It is readily seen that the remaining ODE

$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{(z-1)^2+A_+}\sqrt{(z+1)^2+A_-}$$

is separable, although expressing solutions in terms of elementary functions is probably impossible except perhaps for special values of these constants.

Comment: Thanks! But can we leave the answer as :$$xy+z=C$$ to the question given? I mean if we have a differential equation of the form, $F(x,y,\frac{dy}{dx})=0$ then we generally take, $f(x,y,c)=$ as the solution, isn't it?( ,where $c$ is an arbitrary constant).

Comment: To confirm the final sentence: solving for $z$ explicitly means first taking the antiderivative of $1/\sqrt{P(z)}$ (for some monic quartic polynomial $P(z)$) and then inverting to get $z(t)$. This is not entirely as impossible as it sounds: such antiderivatives are elliptic integrals, and these can generally be inverted to get elliptic functions…but I wouldn’t care to attempt it myself.

Comment: @Semiclassical I don't consider elliptic integrals to be elementary functions (I have already reduced the result to an incomplete one). It is very rare for them to be taught at the university level as well.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I would be delighted if you please consider responding to my comment , i.e https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722687/solve-the-differential-equation-fracdxyzx-fracdyxyz-fracdzx2/4722699#comment10006160_4722699.

Comment: @ThomasFinley the two integrals of motion define a 1-dimensional curve in (x,y,z) space for most values of the constants so technically speaking the problem is completely solved. The only thing that solving the last equation provides is a natural parametrization of that curve in terms of $t$. It is plausible that that's exactly what your professor had in mind.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Thanks for responding! Then to be precise, I can consider the two equations, i.e $$xy+z=C$$ and $$x^2+y^2-z^2=C$$ as the *complete* answer to the question, considering *the way it's posed* ? And this will be final question.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @ThomasFinley this is correct.

Comment: You can see that for yourself if you take differentials of  the two integrals of motions and solve for $dx,dy$ in terms of $dz$. You should recover the differential equality posed in the question.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg If possible, then can you share, what was the motivation behind your consideration of the functions $xy+z,x^2+y^2-z^2$ ? Is it some standard trick, or is it a result of your long experience of working with equations like these?

Comment: I was just trying to eliminate the first and second group of terms in the dx/dt, dy/dt equations and they ended up being total derivatives.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Thanks for sharing!